# What will happen if I upload a spreadsheet into a list with a workflow set to start for each new item?

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow

This is a theoretical question at this point, but important for the design of a process I am being asked to spec.

I am designing a process such that the source material for a list will be generated outside of SharePoint and subsequently uploaded into a list.

I would like for each new list item generated by this upload to kick off a workflow. However, the list will be fairly large (about 2000 items).

Is there any reason to be concerned that some/all of the resulting workflows will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, yes every row from the spreadsheet will kick off a new workflow. Sharepoint internally throttles the workflow processing to 50 being executed at once I believe it is. So depending on the complexity of the workflow and the number of items, you should be ok, it might just take some time to work through all of the items.

With farms being widely different from installation to installation, it's hard to say if this would negatively impact your farm. In the general sense thought, Sharepoint has the internal throttles to handle this load.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to test this through thought experiments before proposing it as a solution. This definitely helps.